# Output javascript code to textarea field

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Why a code like this:

```
 "<div id=""> </div><script async="true" type="text/javascript" src=""></script>"
```

Won't display graphically into a text area field like this:

```
 <?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; ?>
 <textarea placeholder="<?php echo $settings['placeholder']; ?>" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" type="text/javascript" class="widefat" cols="20" rows="2" ref="<?php echo $groupid; ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo htmlentities( $value ); ?></textarea>
```

Any help? 
Thank You!

Comment: type="text/javascript" doesn't belong to a textarea

Comment: What is `$value`

Comment: yet alone a "type" of any sorts.

Comment: What type of field supports text/javascript?

Comment: Only `<script>` supports `type="text/javascript"` Your markup is just all wrong and it isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to create a field inside a WP plugin, to display the code graphically